# Not able to show matched data from database in listview

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim i As Integer
    Dim itm As ListViewItem
    Dim str(7) As String
    Dim provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String
    Dim connString As String
    Dim Errors As String

    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    dataFile = "Trojans.accdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    Errors = ""

    For i = 1 To 4
        Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(path(i))
        For Each File In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path(i), "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            Dim fs As New FileInfo(File)

            Label4.Text = fs.FullName
            TextBox4.Text = _Info.mdsc(fs.FullName).ToUpper
            Try
                Using myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connString)
                    myConnection.Open()
                    Dim strg As String
                    strg = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE MD5='" & TextBox4.Text
                    Using cmd2 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(strg, myConnection)
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("MD5", TextBox4.Text)
                        Using dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader
                            If dr.HasRows Then
                                dr.Read()
                                If TextBox4.Text = dr("MD5").ToString Then
                                    Dim show As String = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE MD5='" & TextBox4.Text
                                    Label10.Text = Label10.Text + 1
                                    str(0) = fs.Name
                                    str(1) = show
                                    str(2) = _Info.getSHA1Hash(fs.FullName)
                                    str(3) = _Info.getSHA256Hash(fs.FullName)
                                    str(4) = _Info.GetCRC32(fs.FullName)
                                    str(5) = fs.FullName
                                    str(6) = NativeMethods.FormatBytes(fs.Length) & " (" & fs.Length & " bytes)"
                                    itm = New ListViewItem(str)
                                    ListView1.Items.Add(itm) 'Added this but still no go
                                    MsgBox("Found: " & dr("MD5") & "!")
                                Else
                                    MsgBox("Error")
                                End If
                            Else
                                MsgBox("Error")
                            End If
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                'MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
            Label5.Text += 1
            If Label5.Text < ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
                ProgressBar1.Value = Label5.Text
            End If
        Next
    Next

    myConnection.Close()
```

I am trying to search a path,hash a file and show current hash in textbox4 at the same time searching ms database for the hash and if its their show corresponding info from database to list-view. Everything works ok except it does not add the data that is matched to list view.

Comment: you need to add the listviewitem to the listview items collection

Comment: i added `ListView1.Items.Add(itm)` but it is still not showing the matched items, i must be still missing something. cheers.

Comment: strg = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE MD5='" & TextBox4.Text

First Replace with this:

'strg = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE MD5=@MD5"'

Comment: **Arun Sharma** you are a legend it it working now

Comment: if you didnt have an empty Try/Catch, the code would have been able to report the problem

Comment: thank **Plutonix** i am not a high-level user but know a little and appricate all the help i can get cheers